# Getting name of relation from Optimized Logical Plan of Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have following optimized logical plan in Spark:

[image]

The highlighted part shows `LogicalRelation` node in the optimized query plan which is created from a csv file as shown below:

```
val empDataSet = sparkSession.read.option("delimiter",";").csv("/home/dataset/employees.csv")
  .toDF("emp_no","birth_date","first_name","last_name","gender","hire_date")
  .createOrReplaceTempView("employees")
```

But instead of showing the alias I provided while creating the DF or the original csv file name, it is showing the node with `csv` written against it. Is there a way I can get either the original file name or the alias  for a particular `Relation` node from the optimized plan?